# Where do we add global code in Cypress ver 10+?

Tags: javascript, cypress, uncaught-exception

[uncaught exception](https://on.cypress.io/uncaught-exception-from-application)
I found the following answer to solve the problem, but as you know we no longer have `support/index.js` file with Cypress version 10 and higher.

```
import './commands'
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from failing the test
  return false
})
```

How can I use this block of code with Cypress version 10 and higher. Potentially in my cypress.config.js file to solve uncaught exception error?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to add an event handler within the test itself, that way you avoid globally hiding all uncaught exceptions.

In addition, test the error message to see if it is the expected error:

```js
it('tests with uncaught exceptions', () => {

  cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err) => 
    return error.message.contains('Trouble') ? false : true
  })

  cy.visit('/')

  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With Cypress 10+, [the support file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file) now lives in either `cypress/support/e2e.js` (for e2e tests) or `cypress/support/component.js` (for component tests). You should be able to add that code block to the relevant support file and achieve the same result as Cypress 9 and below.

Comment: Hello @agoff, Thank you for the info. It solved my that problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Cypress version 10 and above, you can add the exception in support>e2e.js to handle it globally for all the spec files.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.